# C++ Using allocator and initializer with boost circular buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, allocator, circular-buffer

I am trying to figure out how to use the following constructor for boost::circular_buffer:

```
circular_buffer(capacity_type buffer_capacity, size_type n, const_reference item, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

I have a custom class:

```
template<class T> class Custom
{
  public:

    Custom() :
      time(0.0)
    {}

    double time;
    T data_;
};
```

With my circular buffer defined using the constructor taking in just a capacity:

```
boost::circular_buffer<Custom<T>> buffer(10);
```

I have not worked much with allocators, and I want to initialize my buffer with default/empty/zero values at construction, and it seems that the constructor mentioned above is the way to go about it using boost::circular_buffer, however I am not exactly sure how to with boost constructor. If it were an ordinary vector I assume I can do the following:

```
int num_elements = 10;
Custom<T> custom;
std::vector<Custom<T>> buffer(10, custom);
```

I could not really find any examples on this specifically, so any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like your `std::vector` call where you do not specify an allocator for `Custom` and use the default, you can do the same thing with `boost::circular_buffer`.  The only difference is `boost::circular_buffer` has an extra parameter allowing you set the capacity and number of default constructed objects in the buffer at the same time.  That means if you want a full `boost::circular_buffer` then you would use:

```
int num_elements = 10;
Custom<T> custom;
boost::circular_buffer<Custom<T>> buffer(num_elements, num_elements, custom);
```

Which give you a `boost::circular_buffer` with a capacity of `num_elements` with `num_elements` default allocated objects in it.

You could also have:

```
boost::circular_buffer<Custom<T>> buffer(num_elements, num_elements/2, custom);
```

Which sets the capacity to `num_elements` but only fills half the buffer (`num_elements/2`) with default allocated objects.

Really the only reason you would have to use a different allocator is if you want the allocator to use a different allocation scheme (how it actually allocates memory in the system) than the default.

Comment: Ok this is great. Question: Now when I push back it will start filling at the end since all items are filled, and my size will return num_elements. Is there any way around this? Basically I wanted default values so whenever I accessed buffer[index] that was not populated yet but still within capacity, it would not error out. But I kind of wanted the behavior of empty buffer where size only returns items I specifically pushed back and when I explicitly pushed back it would start at the beginning (ignoring default). Not sure if thats even possible, might have to overload some operators/methods?

Comment: @arias_JC Just like a vector it is either one or the other.  either you fill it by default and override with `operator[]` or you set it's capacity and you fill it with `push_back()`.  You could wrap the buffer in your own class and provide the functionality you want if you really must have it.